# Tkinter button isnt running the function, even though I have correct formatting

Tags: python, tkinter

I know this question gets asked alot but I've gone through all similar questions and cant seem to find whats wrong with my code.
'''

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
encrypt = Text(root, height=10)
encrypt.insert(1.0, 'Enter text to be encrypted')
decrypt = Text(root, state=DISABLED, height=10)
submit = Button(root, text='Submit',command = decrypt)
e = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('./secret/alphabet.txt')]
d = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('./secret/jumble.txt')]
encrypt.grid(row=1,column=1)
decrypt.grid(row=2,column=1)
submit.grid(row=3,column=1)
def decrypt():
    print('hey')
    encrypt.config(state=DISABLED)
    for i in encrypt.get("1.0","end-1c"):
        index = e.index(i)
        print(i)
root.mainloop()
```

'''

Comment: You're using `decrypt` both as a widget and a function. How is tkinter supposed to know which one to run when you click the button?

Comment: Thank you so much. Can't believe I oversaw that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must change decrypt text name and define decrypt func above

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def decrypt():
    print('hey')
    encrypt.config(state=DISABLED)
    for i in encrypt.get("1.0","end-1c"):
        index = e.index(i)
        print(i)


encrypt = Text(root, height=10)
encrypt.insert(1.0, 'Enter text to be encrypted')
decrypta = Text(root, state=DISABLED, height=10)
submit = Button(root, text='Submit', command=decrypt)
e = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('./secret/alphabet.txt')]
d = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('./secret/jumble.txt')]
encrypt.grid(row=1,column=1)
decrypta.grid(row=2,column=1)
submit.grid(row=3,column=1)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I used decrypt as both a widget and a function. Sorry I just oversaw it.